# Missing result when using threadid parallel computing python

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, python-multithreading

I'm running code on a server and splitting across the 4 cores I have. The results are as expected when I have 3 parameter values but when I have 4, it only gives 3 results, code is like:

```
parameter_values = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5] 

def runsoncores(threadid):
    np.random.seed(threadid)
    tf.random.set_seed(threadid)    

    parameter_for_sim = parameter_values[threadid]
# **runs simulation here with the parameter value**
    filename = 'results_' + str(parameter_for_sim) + '.npy'
    np.save(filename,samples)

def parallel_run(threadid, gpu):
    with tf.name_scope(gpu):
        with tf.device(gpu):
            runoncores(threadid)
    return



gpu_list = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
num_threads = len(gpu_list)

print(num_threads)
threads = list()
start = time.time()
for index in range(num_threads):
    x = threading.Thread(target=parallel_run, args=(index,gpu_list[index].name))
    threads.append(x)
    x.start()

for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
    thread.join()

end = time.time()
print('Threaded time taken: ', end-start)
```

What is happening and how can I get the same number of results as input values? Thanks!

Comment: What is ``threadid``? Do you have as many threads as parameters?

Comment: I was copying an example, but I think threadid is the core number that the job gets sent to and I have 4 cores and 4 parameters

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the example. *threadid* would have to be a value between 0 & 3 (incl.) and is therefore unlikely to represent either a core or thread id. But tell us more. I'm often wrong

Comment: Yes, I thought threadid would be 0-3, representing the 4 cores, and when I run the code with only 3 parameter values, the results have 1-3, but no 0

Comment: I think we need to see more code. As it stands it makes no sense

Comment: Code updated - the part at the bottom was probably useful, sorry!

Comment: Is ``len(gpu_list)`` actually equal to ``len(parameter_values)``?

Comment: Hopefully, someone who isn't on macOS will be able to try this. Sadly, Tensorflow doesn't currently offer GPU device support on macOS

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I checked the information on the server and it says 8 CPUs with 2 threads per core

Comment: "8 CPUs with 2 threads per core" That's not the number of **G**PUs.

Comment: Is there a command to get GPU info from the linux command line on the server? I am unsuccessful so far..

Comment: Re-reading the actual question... Looks to me as though *num_threads == 3*. You  might want to try printing that out. Also, you should consider portability when writing **any** code. On macOS, this code will do nothing because *list_logical_devices('GPU')* will return an empty list

Comment: Thanks @BrutusForcus, it actually prints out as 4, so I am still confused! A good point